# Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors: strange case

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Why is this expression:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{k+mg}{l} & -k\\ 
-k & \frac{k+mg}{l}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\rho_1\\\rho_2 
\end{pmatrix}=\omega^2\begin{pmatrix}
m & 0\\ 
0 & m
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\rho_1\\\rho_2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

a matricial form for equation for eigenvalues and eigenvectors? I was told that the generical expression of the equation for eigenvalues and eigenvectors is $A\bf{x}=\lambda \bf{x}$... How can I obtain eigenvalues and eigenvectors from the first expression that I have written?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ is the big matrix on the left and $x = (\rho_1, \rho_2)^T$, then the equation you have written can be rewritten as
$$ Ax = \omega^2 m I x$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. But this can thus be written as $Ax = \omega^2 m x$, so this is just the eigenvalue-eigenvector equation with eigenvalue $\lambda = \omega^2 m$.

Comment: Thanks but my book says that the form of eigenvalues is $\lambda=\omega^2$.. how can I find it?

Comment: I have solved my doubt :) but I have an other question: the book says also that normalized eigenvectors are $v_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2m} }(1,1)^T$ and $v_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2m} }(1,-1)^T$.. why there is $\sqrt{m}$? thanks a lot

Comment: The "norm" of a vector depends on the choice of norm. It sounds like, here, the norm of a vector is given by
$$ \|(x_1, x_2)\|^2 = m(x_1^2 + x_2^2) $$